# Windows IIS test server setup

Tags: iis, networking

I picked up a new server to do some testing and need of a little help in setting up my environment at home.

Here is what I would like to do: The test server will be used to test new code and configurations for a SaaS product. I would like from my laptop to enter www.acme.com and have it hit the server. The server is connected to a wireless router.

I have windows server 2008 with IIS running on an an IP of 192.168.1.4.

What is the best way to set this up? I want to hit the test server for www.acme.com and not go out to the internet.

Do i need to mess with the LMHosts file?

Thanks for the help. Im sure its easy but have never done this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your dev box edit the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file and add the line:

192.168.1.4 acme.com

That should do the trick...

Comment: so i can browse 192.168.1.4 and the default page comes up but when i do this it still goes out to the net. 192.168.1.4 acme.com ideas?

Comment: if you edit the hosts file on your laptop and add the line above when your laptop tries to access acme.com or www.acme.com it will go to address 192.168.1.4 instead of out to the internet. If your laptop is Windows the hosts file is located at:

c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

if your laptop is a Mac or Linux the hosts file is located at:

/etc/hosts

If you edit that file your server will look like acme.com to your laptop.